# Connect Adafruit_PCA9685- I2C interface in Raspberry pi Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, i2c, servo

How to Connect Adafruit_PCA9685- I2C using Raspberry Pi and Python?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Actually this an answer

Comment: Where is the question? :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could be able to individually 16 servo motor run at a time using Raspberry pi and python.I used **reconnect_io_func()** function which will check is connected with raspberry pi, if not then will continue try to connect until successful connect.Then will be run servo motor value

```
from __future__ import division
import Adafruit_PCA9685


def reconnect_io_func():
    try:
        pwm = Adafruit_PCA9685.PCA9685()
        return pwm
    except Exception as error:
        if "Remote I/O error" in (error):
            reconnect_io = True
            while reconnect_io:
                try:
                    # print("while Error: "+str(error))
                    pwm = Adafruit_PCA9685.PCA9685()
                    # print(pwm)
                    reconnect_io = False
                    return pwm
                except Exception as error:
                    # print((error))
                    reconnect_io = True


servo_min = 150  # Min pulse length out of 4096
servo_max = 600  # Max pulse length out of 4096
pwm = reconnect_io_func()
pwm.set_pwm_freq(60)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    pwm.set_pwm(0, 0, 420)
    pwm.set_pwm(1, 0, 420)
    pwm.set_pwm(2, 0, 307)
    pwm.set_pwm(3, 0, 420)
    pwm.set_pwm(4, 0, 307)
    pwm.set_pwm(5, 0, 307)
    pwm.set_pwm(6, 0, 307)
    pwm.set_pwm(7, 0, 307)
    pwm.set_pwm(8, 0, 0)
    # print (" i am here")
```